# How to install .sis or .jar apps in Windows Phone?

Tags: apps

I tried to download operamini in .sis and .jar format. but still the format is not supported. why is that? i can't download other application except from the marketplace. can somebody help me?

Answer (score 12):

`.jar` is the Java archive file format and Java code cannot run on Windows Phone.

`.sis` is an archive file for apps and executable's meant for the Symbian operating system. Hence, even these cannot run on Windows Phone.

If you want to convert an app that is available on another platform to make it usable on Windows Phone, you can either rewrite the application using one of the `.NET` framework languages.

For a global solution to writing code for multiple platforms you could use `C++`.

Answer (score 6):

you are correct. you only can download apps from the official Marketplace.

If you have a developer unlocked phone you can install applications with the .xap extension made for Windows Phone.